# RxSwift propagating a value through a chain of flatMaps

Tags: swift, rx-swift

So I have some RxSwift code where I want to perform a chain of asynchronous operations, all composed using observables. `flatMap` is the way to do this, and it works great, however it doesn't seem to be able to pass variables down the chain that I can figure out. This is best illustrated by some pseudocode

Assume have 3 functions

```
class Connection {
    static func establish(address:String) -> Observable<Connection>
    func sendData(data:String) -> Observable<Int> // num bytes written or something
    func close() -> Observable<Void>
}
```

And I want to call them in a chain such that we connect, send, then close. Something like this

```
Connection.establish(host)
    .flatMap{ connection in connection.sendData("foo") }
    .flatMap{ numBytes in ????.close() }
    .subscribeNext{ /* all done */ }
```

The problem is that `flatMap` doesn't pass it's input parameters down the chain, so that the closure passed to `subscribeNext` doesn't have access to the `connection` object, and as such it can't call close.

I could do some awful hack like the following, but I'd really rather not!

```
var connection:Connection?
Connection.establish(host)
    .flatMap{ c in 
        connection = c
        return c.sendData("foo") 
    }
    .flatMap{ numBytes in connection!.close() }
    .subscribeNext{ /* all done */ }
```

In the C# version of Rx, this is solved by using an overload to `SelectMany` which takes a second closure, which combines the 2 values (usually into a Tuple) and then *that* thing is propagated down the chain. I've written this as an extension for RxSwfit, and it works as follows:

```
Connection.establish(host)
    .flatMap(
        { connection in connection.sendData("foo") },
        combine: { ($0, $1) }) // tupleify
    .flatMap{ (connection, numbytes) in connection.close() }
    .subscribeNext{ /* all done */ }
```

This is all well and good, but my primary question is - Is there a better way to do this which is built into RxSwift as it currently stands?

Additionally, writing this extension method is not simple nor easy. I basically re-implemented FlatMap from scratch by copy/pasting the one in [MiniRxSwift](https://github.com/borland/StockFighterApiClient/blob/master/MiniRxSwift.swift#L322) and modifying it. If we have to write this extension, is there a better way to implement it using RxSwift constructs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to do what you want "using RxSwift constructs."

```
Connection.establish(host)
    .flatMap { Observable.combineLatest(Observable.just($0), $0.sendData("foo")) }
    .flatMap { connection, _ in connection.close() }
    .subscribe(onNext: { /* all done */ })
```

or if you don't mind inserting into a map you could:

```
Connection.establish(host)
    .flatMap { connection in
        connection.sendData("foo").map { (connection, $0) }
    }
    .flatMap { connection, _ in connection.close() }
    .subscribe(onNext: { /* all done */ })
```

Note that `combineLatest` and `map` were both in the library from the beginning.

Comment: That's indeed the cleanest way to do that. But what about combining the Singles? What if the methods return Single rather than Observable? Would we have to cast them up to Observable just to be able to use combineLatest and then cast them back down asSingle() after that? Would really appreciate your take on that topic. Thanks.

Comment: That is one of the problems with using `Single`. The library as it stands has limited scope for dealing with them so they often need to be cast into observables. I usually avoid using them.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in your `establish` function. It probably looks like this:

```
static func establish(address:String) -> Observable<Connection> {
    return Observable.create { observer in
        //create connection
        observer.onNext(connection)
        observer.onCompleted()

        return AnonymousDisposable { connection.close() }
    }
}
```

When your `observer` being disposed, it will also close your connection.
And I think this is one of the best option here.

However, we can passed down the connection though the chain by using `combineLatest` or `flatMap` or other functions. But it will be tedious :)

---

**Reply to Orion Edwards**

> 'm not sure this would work; In my example the disposable is never
>   actually disposed, we want to close the connection as soon as the
>   operation completes instead

Well, I'm pretty sure this is how RxSwift's people would do.
If you got your results, either it `completed` or `error` out, you dispose the observer. And if you want to do it again, then you `re-subscribe` it.

You can use one of these functions in order to dispose it:

- Using `take` family: `take(1)`, `takeUntil`...
- Call `dispose()` on observers when you finish. (discourage)
- Use `debug()` to see when an observer is disposed
- ...

Comment: I'm not sure this would work; In my example the disposable is never actually disposed, we want to close the connection as soon as the operation completes instead

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer. I concede your example is probably the best way to do it for the specific case of `connect` -> `send` -> `close`, but it doesn't solve the general problem of passing a value through a chain of flatMaps. For example, how would it work if I wanted to do `connect` -> `send` -> `send2` -> `send3` -> `close` ?? Thanks